# Question-user matching on Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, questions, users

Is there any sort of expert matching on Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange? Does SO / SE take any implicit measures of expertise to influence how it distributes questions? Do newbie questions go to the same users as questions that would require a lot of expertise to answer?

Comment: This would be an interesting feature. Just about impossible to implement in a satisfactory way, though.

Answer (score 5):

No, **all** questions go to **all** people who want to see them.

In other words, questions aren't *sent* to anyone. Users can view and answer any question that is posted. Most "expert" users will generally focus their attention on questions with a particular set of tags, so be sure to tag your question appropriately for what topic(s) it covers.

Comment: But in how they distribute questions, do they take into account expertise?

Comment: @user There is no "distribution" of questions.

Answer (score 2):

People just find the questions they want to answer. The questions on the **active** tab are just those with recent edits or answers. The only way people are given questions they are best-equipped to answer is ability to set **interesting** and **ignored** tags.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any sort of expert matching on Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange?

No (hmm, maybe reputation).

> Does SO / SE take any implicit measures of expertise to influence how it distributes questions?

No.

> Do newbie questions go to the same users as questions that would require a lot of expertise to answer?

No.

Comment: I know, but my question accounts in the distribution of unanswered questions. You don't see every question that is asked, but rather a subset.

Comment: @user, actually, you do see every question that is asked, unless you explicitly block some by using ignored tags as described in Simon's answer. (Or unless you're a slow reader. Two thousand questions a day isn't that many.)

Comment: @user: "Unanswered questions" is not a distribution, it is a filter. If your question has no answers, or no upvoted answers, you will find it there.

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 when this question was asked and up to 2022 the system that powers Stack Overflow and all the Stack Exchanges sites hadn't a "distribution" feature to assign questions to users in order to be answered by them. The system is not a *resource allocation*, or a "matching" system.

I don't known when it started but the system has review queues where certain questions are sent to be reviewed regarding if they are on topic and meet the quality standards.

In Stack Overflow, at the end of 2022 and March 2023 some questions from new users are sent to Staging Ground, again to be *reviewed* to a special environment, not to be *answered*.

Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites work, the other way, users willing to know what content is available might watch tags, use filters, subsbribe to the site newsletter, among others. Then they should decide if they find a question interesting and challenging enough to answer it.

## References

- [What are review queues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reviews-intro)
- [How might the Staging Ground & the new Ask Wizard work on the Stack Exchange network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377768/289691)